# Unable to Download Blob Programmatically

Tags: azure, powershell

We have multiple blobs in an azure storage container, when we use powershell to download the blobs (files), 8 out of the 9 files download, however the 9th one fails. There is absolutely nothing different about this file, the only thing I've noticed in the blob properties the "content MD5" is blank, however the other 8 have a value. Not sure what this is or if it has anything to do wit it, I was hoping someone could shed some light as to why this is one file is not downloading..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using Azure Storage PowerShell Cmdlets or have written something of your own? Please share your code.

Comment: Just using powershell to download file using storage context

Comment: @NorrinRad could you please share the code ? Also if there are any error messages while running the script

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for downloading files from Azure Blob

```
function Get-DLLFile
{
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]   $connectionString,             
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String[]] $blobsName,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]   $container,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]   $filePath
    ) 


    Try
{
 foreach ($blobName in $blobsName) 
        {

    $file = $filePath + $blobName
    $fileAvailable = Get-Item -Path $file -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($null -eq $fileAvailable)
    {
        $ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $connectionString
        New-Item -Path $filePath -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null       
        Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $blobName -Container $container -Destination $filePath -Context $ctx -Force | out-null

    }
    }
}
Catch
{
   $_.Exception.Message
}
}
Get-DLLFile -blobsName "File1.csv","File2.json" -container "myContainer" -connectionString "$(BlobConnectionString)" -filePath "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Download"
```

Hope this should work, if not Please share the exception you are getting.